# Why this program loops endlessly sometimes and not always

Tags: c, c89

I successfully solved a programming project from a book named "C Programming: A modern approach" by K.N. King.

The program works fine but goes into endless loop sometimes. I am not getting the reason behind this.

I used a random function which will give random values ranging from 0 to 3 and I have used sufficient conditions to handle all the four random values.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
int main()
{
    char walk[10][10];
    int direction,currenti=5,currentj=5;

    int i,j;
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<10; j++)
        {
            walk[i][j]='.';
        }
    }
    srand((unsigned) time(NULL));
    for(i=0; i<26;)
    {
        direction=rand()%4;
        printf("%d ",direction);
        if(direction==0&&walk[currenti][currentj-1]=='.'&&(currentj-1)>0&&(currentj-1)<10)
        {
            currentj=currentj-1;
            walk[currenti][currentj]='A'+i;
            i++;
        }
        else if(direction==1&&walk[currenti][currentj+1]=='.'&&(currentj+1)>0&&(currentj+1)<10)
        {
            currentj=currentj+1;
            walk[currenti][currentj]='A'+i;
            i++;
        }
        else if(direction==2&&walk[currenti-1][currentj]=='.'&&(currenti-1)>0&&(currenti-1)<10)
        {
            currenti=currenti-1;
            walk[currenti][currentj]='A'+i;
            i++;
        }
        else if(direction==3&&walk[currenti+1][currentj]=='.'&&(currenti+1)>0&&(currenti+1)<10)
        {
            currenti=currenti+1;
            walk[currenti][currentj-1]='A'+i;
            i++;
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<10; j++)
        {
            printf("%c ",walk[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have missed the last else part, which was supposed to handle the corner case scenario.

Comment: Moving the `i++` out of the 3rd `for` clause is a very bad idea.

Comment: Have you tried printing all the values for `walk` after each time you change it? What happens if the program walks {up, up, left left, down down, right, up}?

Comment: @emmrk since I used rand()%4, so the value of direction will take values (0,1,2,3) and I have made all the four conditions for them...what you meant by not using sufficient conditions?

Comment: @SouravGhosh I have handled the corner case in if conditions itself, like in first if condition, I have specified (currentj-1) should not go beyond the array range ie 0 or 9

Comment: The code sometimes only tests that the next position is in bounds after it has accessed the array out of bounds.  Also, it tests for `> 0` where it should probably test for `>= 0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only having a quick look, my guess would be because in your main `for` loop, you only increment `i` on certain conditions, and it is likely that none of them or met, which means `i++` would then not be called.

Best way to verify this would be to put an `else` clause where you handle the case properly, by printing a message, or putting an assert if you should never reach that case.

As a measure of precaution, when you have `if`/`else if` clauses, you should always have an `else` clause where you handle the "if all else fails" value, where you either handle the error properly, or assert if the code should never reach the else clause.

Also, as a side note, you should consider using spaces in order to make your code a bit easier to read, such as:

```
if (direction == 3 && walk[currenti + 1][currentj] == '.' && (currenti + 1) > 0 && (currenti + 1) < 10)
```

Comment: The range test should come before accessing the array out of bounds, and the lower bound should be `>= 0`, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

When you enter a corner and the array around it contains only dots you will have an infinite loop.
This happens only sometimes because of the random behaviour of course

Answer (score 0):

Because your walk is random you could enter condition when it is not possible to move further whatever the number and `i` would not get increased

Example of infinite loop ( your program walks from 1 to 9 )

```
1 2 3 . . . . . . .
8 9 4 . . . . . . .
7 6 5 . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
```

At step 9 your program would get blocked whatever would be the next `direction` as it has blocked all its possible next move.

There are of course a lot of variant of this kind of situation, but it also mean that there are situation where your program blocked itself before performing its 26 steps.

You should detect this kind of condition to terminate your loop early.